# How to Configure the federated search in Salesforce, I saw this in the Summer17 release guide

Tags: api

Federated search in Salesforce Configuration

How can I configure a service that is compatible in OpenSearch in salesforce

More Info : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_search_federated_search.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your webservice is compatible with Open Search, or else build a wrapper using solr.

And configuration on Salesforce side is pretty simple, Create it as a new external service.

[image: New External Service Screen]

Regards,

Praneel PIDIKITI